# Error importing a servlet project in Eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am importing a project in eclipse which is made in Servlet and JSP. Now the JSP part is working fine but the servlet part is throwing null pointer exception.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it 
from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
com.pathology.util.DbUtil.getConnection(DbUtil.java:21)
com.pathology.dao.LoginDao.authenticateUser(LoginDao.java:27)
com.pathology.controller.LoginController.doPost(LoginController.java:42)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
```

I have tried everything and also saw other answers but got no luck.

Comment: This is not a problem with importing the project, it's a runtime error. The stacktrace indicates exactly where the problem starts. Please check your DB initialization code.

Comment: @ernest_k  Yaa got it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now solved. There was an error in **db.properties** file.